# Material Ui Textfield Pattern matching

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Hi I am new to material ui I trying to textField only allows number,using patter but not working and also tried with number type it working But need with pattern matching only

Thanks for Help

```
<TextField
  name="salary"
  value={salary}
  variant="outlined"
  size="small"                          
  fullWidth
  autoComplete="off"
  pattern="[0-9]+"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

it just makes an error for input :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = {
  input: {
    "&:invalid": {
      border: "red solid 2px"
    }
  }
};
function App({ classes }) {
  return (
    <TextField
      inputProps={{ className: classes.input, pattern: "[0-9]{1,15}" }}
    />
  );
}
const StyledApp = withStyles(styles)(App);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StyledApp />, rootElement);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-pattern-forked-lho7h?file=/src/index.js)